# Why my file don't write text inserted?

Tags: blackberry

I' doing an API for Black Berry but now I have a problem, the file don't save text inserted , for example when I write on application running : Hello , I guess that "Hello" is saving in EditField pt_nombre,

```
name = new LabelField("Nombre");
pt_nombre = new FixedWidthEditField();



String a = pt_nombre.getText();
String nom = name.getText();

String fullPath = "file:///SDCard/xxx.txt";

try {
    FileConnection fconn = (FileConnection) Connector.open(fullPath, Connector.READ_WRITE);
    if (fconn.exists()) {
        fconn.delete();
    }

    fconn.create();
    OutputStream os = fconn.openOutputStream();

    os.write(nombre.getBytes());
    os.write("\r\n".getBytes());
    os.write(a.getBytes());

    fconn.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Oh noes!!1! " + e.toString());
}
```

When I check the xxx.txt only are write the Label, Nombre: but the written text in EditField isn't !! help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure this code even compiles? I don't see where nombre is declared (even to the extend that name and pt_nombre are 'declared'); nor is there anywhere that you set a value into pt_nombre, so I don't know what you rexpect to see in the file.

Answer (score 0):

you should check FixedWidthEditField getText function.
will it return the text that user input